# jQuery Showing Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a website and as i don't have good knowledge of jQuery so please help me creating this website. I want to thank all those beautiful and intelligent people who will be helping me in this project. Now coming to the issue, i want a webpage having preloader which appears on the screen until all the content of webpage has been loaded.As soon as the content loads the preloader disappears. I am using Brackets editor and its showing me error (small red cross) in jQuery code that i have written and also preloader is not disappearing after the content is loaded. i am using jQuery version 1.12.4. I am providing all codes that have written. Please help me in solving this issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="preloader">
    <div class="status">
        <div class="status-mes"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.preloader {
    background: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.status-mes {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -40px 0 0 -40px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-indent: -12345px;
    border-top: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    border-right: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    border-left: 5px solid #ffb900;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: spinner 700ms infinite linear;
    animation: spinner 700ms infinite linear;
    z-index: 10000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spinner {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';

    jQuery(document).on('ready', function(){

        $(window).on('load', function() { 
            $('.status').fadeOut();
            $('.preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); 
        }); 

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You don't need to use window load inside document ready callback. Remove the window load listener and put the fadeout code directly inside ready callback

Comment: Hi Sandip,
Thank you for answering me. Can you please edit my code and post it here.

Comment: Unless you want images loaded, in which case use the window load event only

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.status').fadeOut();
            $('.preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

```css
.preloader {
    background: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.status-mes {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -40px 0 0 -40px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-indent: -12345px;
    border-top: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    border-right: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    border-left: 5px solid #ffb900;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: spinner 700ms infinite linear;
    animation: spinner 700ms infinite linear;
    z-index: 10000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spinner {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preloader">
    <div class="status">
        <div class="status-mes"></div>
    </div>
</div>
 <p> Welcome to my website!!! </p>
```

Comment: But preloader will disapear when DOM will be loaded. OP wants to hide preloader when wil be loaded full page. Use `$(window).on('load'`